# How to resolve error with storing selected option into database using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

On submit I get the following error

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'item_selected' cannot be null

`Ticket.php`:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="ticketSupport.php" role="form">
    <div class="messages"></div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_item_select" class="mbr-white text-center">Select item <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                    <select id="form_item_select" name="item_select" class="custom-select" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                        <option>Select item</option>
                        <option value="theme1">Example template (1)</option>
                        <option value="theme2">Example 2 template (5)</option>
                        <option value="theme3">Example 3 template (15)</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_help_select" class="mbr-white text-center">Help topic <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                    <select id="form_help_select" name="help_selected" class="custom-select" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                        <option>Select help topic</option>
                        <option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>
                        <option value="General inquiry">General inquiry</option>
                        <option value="Report a problem">Report a problem</option>
                        <option value="Report a problem / Access Issue">Report a problem / Access Issue</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email" class="mbr-white text-center">Email <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required." value="<?php echo $userData['email']; ?>">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_phone" class="mbr-white text-center">Phone number</label>
                    <input id="form_phone" type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Please enter your phone number *" required="required" data-error="Valid phone is required." value="<?php echo $userData['phone']; ?>">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_message" class="mbr-white text-center">Ticet details <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                    <p class="mbr-white small">Please describe your issue</p>
                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Details on the reason(s) for opening the ticket. *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block sgn" value="Create ticket">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`ticketSupport.php` page:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_name";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,
    $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tickets (item_selected, help_selected, 
email, phone, message) 
VALUES (:item_selected, :help_selected, :email, :phone, :message)");
$stmt->bindParam(':item_selected', $item_selected);
$stmt->bindParam(':help_selected', $help_selected);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);

// insert a row
$item_selected = $_POST["item_selected"];
$help_selected = $_POST["help_selected"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$stmt->execute();


header('Location: ticket-status');
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Where is the problem? I want to store option in a database when user selects it.

Comment: You can skip a lot of redundant steps by binding directly to the `$_POST` values when executing: `execute([ ':item_selected' => $_POST['item_selected], ... ])`

Comment: Yo need to check that A) The form was actually submitted rather than just running for the first time. B) That the fields on the form ACTUALLY had data in them when the for was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following changes to the item_select combo box

```
<select id="form_item_select" name="item_selected" class="custom-select" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
   <option>Select item</option>
   <option value="theme1">Example template (1)</option>
   <option value="theme2">Example 2 template (5)</option>
   <option value="theme3">Example 3 template (15)</option>
 </select>
```

change the name of the field and don't allow empty selection as this field is mandatory have a default value like this

```
<select id="form_item_select" name="item_select" class="custom-select" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
 <option value="theme1" selected>Example template (1)</option>
 <option value="theme2">Example 2 template (5)</option>
 <option value="theme3">Example 3 template (15)</option>   
</select>
```